# How do I use profiling to find execution time for both SQL and MongoDB query in PHP?

Tags: php, sql, mongodb, oracle11g, php-mongodb

I'm new to PHP and don't know how to use profiling to get the execution time of following queries.
MongoDB query:

```
$collection = new MongoCollection($db,'CUSTOMERS');
$cursor = $collection->find(['CUSTOMER_ID' => intval($id)]);
```

SQL query:

```
$s = oci_parse($c, 'select CUSTOMER_ID
                  from   CUSTOMERS
                  where  CUSTOMER_ID = :un_bv
                  ');
oci_bind_by_name($s, ":un_bv", $_POST['customer_id']);
oci_execute($s);
```

I tried following code for mongodb query but it print a lot of things of which i know nothing.

```
$db->setProfilingLevel(2);
$cursor = $collection->find(['CUSTOMER_ID' => intval($id)]);
$response = $db->system->profile->find();

foreach($response as $obj)
{
    print_r($obj);
}
```

Help me on how to use profiling to get the execution time only.

Comment: You may want to use additional tools like https://tideways.io/ for instance

Comment: @malarzm Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In general you can use microtime() in PHP to test the execution time of a piece of code, in your case the two queries.

See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php

Comment: Thank you for the response, but I would like to know about using profiling though.

Comment: Oh sorry, my bad. Unfortunately I cannot help you with that.